# Animate plants growing along path as camera passes

Tags: animation, path, nla-editor, actions, dynamic-paint

I've created a plant object with a simple growth animation action and arranged many of them along a path in my scene. I've animated my camera moving along this path, and I would like the growth actions to trigger on the plant objects as the camera passes so that the plants grow in front of the camera as it moves. What would be the best way to do this? I've seen dynamic painting used for similar effects but as far as I can tell this can only animate the scale of the plants, whereas I would really like to be able to use it to play my full growth animation.